How much performance penalty is created by split loads in AVX code?
Motivation
I'm working on improving the performance of a numerical simulation engine. This mainly involves re-organizing the memory layouts and access patterns in several ways, re-writing the inner loops in several ways, and finally do some performance comparisons using micro-benchmarks and CPU performance counters.
Problem
I noted that whenever the compiler is able to vectorize the inner loops using AVX2, there's a noticeable increase of performance. At the same time, the value of the CPU performance counter MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.SPLIT_LOADS_PS becomes extremely high, and Intel VTune claims the bottleneck of this item is "100%".
To be clear, this is completely expected - the algorithm reads an array in multiple overlapped "windows" somewhere in the middle, so these inputs are rarely aligned with cachelines (the algorithm itself is out of scope of my question, but a simplified description can be found here). The problem is obviously worsened when it's loaded vector-by-vector instead of value-by-value. Most of these misaligned loads are required by the algorithm, so it's not a surprise that there are many split-loads when AVX2 is used.
What I'm not sure, however, is its performance penalty. According to Intel's own documentation:

Throughout the memory hierarchy, data moves at cache line granularity - 64 bytes per line. Although this is much larger than many common data types, such as integer, float, or double, unaligned values of these or other types may span two cache lines. Recent Intel architectures have significantly improved the performance of such 'split loads' by introducing split registers to handle these cases, but split loads can still be problematic, especially if many split loads in a row consume all available split registers.

Unlike many other Intel CPU performance quirks that are analyzed in depths by many experts, I was unable to find more information. I did a Web search with site:stackoverflow.com split load AVX and site:stackoverflow.com AVX misalign cacheline but was unable to find any specific question that addressed it in the past.
Ultimately, I need to decide whether it's worthwhile to rewrite the AVX inner loops by hand or to insert holes in the data structures to reduce these misaligned loads. It would be a waste of time if there's only a 10% overhead.
Question
In AVX code, how much performance penalty is created by split loads (i.e. compared to the clean case of the equivalent code without any split loads)? Do these performance characteristics differ across different Intel CPU microarchitectures (e.g. Sandy Bridge, Haswell, Skylake, Icelake)? Do differences exist for different vector sizes (AVX-256 and AVX-512)? Does the overhead vary for different working set sizes (L1, L2, L3, DRAM)?
